# no network device found after Kernel update

Tags: debian, kernel, networking, hardware

So I managed to install Debian 5 on an eBox 3300MX (an embedded type computer). I added a custom kernel after getting a basic install done. That was to get the network card to work. After that, I finished with installing, since I was doing a net install, and it worked fine. However, since then, I am unable to get the Debian to use the network card again. The only thing I can think of is that the Kernel updated during the install. I tried booting into the previous working kernel, and that did not work either. I get the error "No network devices found."

However, I can open Network Tools and view devices, and I see the network card, with its MAC address and other info. I have it listed in etc/network/interfaces as auto. Thus, I don't understand why it does not want to work.  I'm not really sure what other info is relevant, so please comment and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that during the first update I did (`apt-get install ntp`), that `ifupdown` was removed. Since I did not immediately reboot, I was able to continue with the net install following this. I discovered this by completely installing Debian again, and carefully looking through the operations during that update (well, and the help of someone who knows much more about Linux than I do). Anyways, all it took to get going again was `apt-get install ifupdown` and now everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [this guide from the debian forum](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=40831).
Looks like the driver from the manufacturer [held low quality](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1052426) and was therefor thrown out at some point.